# Theano: Shared variable not freeing memory after code run

Tags: memory-management, out-of-memory, gpgpu, theano, theano-cuda

I'm running this simple code which copies two large arrays to GPU memory for dot product computation.

```
import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

a = np.asarray(np.random.uniform(-1,1, (10000,40000)), dtype=np.float32)
b = np.asarray(np.random.uniform(-1,1, (40000,20000)), dtype=np.float32)

aa = theano.shared(a)
bb = theano.shared(b)

x = T.matrix()
y = T.matrix()

dd = T.dot(x,y)

ddd = theano.function([], dd, givens=[(x,aa), (y,bb)])

ddd()
```

However, it seems that after each code run (in Spyder), the GPU memory allocated for these shared variables is not freed.

I'm using Titan-X with 12GB of RAM, and I can only run this code twice, the third time it will produce the following error:

```
MemoryError: ('Error allocating 3200000000 bytes of device memory (CNMEM_STATUS_OUT_OF_MEMORY).', "you might consider using 'theano.shared(..., borrow=True)'")
```

Here's my theanorc file:

```
[blas]
ldflags =

[nvcc]
flags=-LC:\Anaconda\libs
compiler_bindir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin

[global]
device = gpu0
floatX = float32
print_active_device = True
optimizer_including = cudnn
allow_gc = True

[lib]
cnmem = 0.8

[dnn]
enabled = True
conv.algo_fwd = time_on_shape_change
conv.algo_bwd_filter = time_on_shape_change
conv.algo_bwd_data = time_on_shape_change
```

I'm monitoring GPU memory usage with nvidia-smi, and I can see that it consumes all 12GB of memory after 3 code runs.

Comment: Try updating your system to the latest available driver for your GPU.

Comment: yes, I'm using the latest driver.

Comment: Is this a Maxwell Titan X or a Pascal Titan X?  Which driver version are you using?  If you exit out of everything (including spyder) does `nvidia-smi` still show the memory utilization?

Comment: If I exit Spyder the memory is freed. Maxwell Titan-X, 372.54 driver.
Actually, the memory if freed if I close Spyder console tab which displays the results, and open a new one, so I don't have to close the entire Spyder app.

Comment: To add more detail: I expect Spyder console session to hold the variables, so I can examine them after the code is run, however, I expect the next code run will overwrite these variables, and it appears that it does not.